# How to communicate between Windows Form app and Web Site?

Tags: winforms, web-services, web, c#-2.0, communication

We developped an C# .Net 2.0 Windows Form application for Windows XP embedded that controls the underlying hardware/device. Now, we need to add a c# .NET 2.0 Web Site (hosting by IIS inside the same device) that can send commands to the Windows Form application (example: Start measuring) and receive data.

What is the best way to do it?

We thought about Web Service, but how the Windows Form application can know when the Web Service will receive a command from the Web Site.

Thank you.

Note: Forbidden to install on the device a Framework .NET 3.x or 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this restriction on .Net 2.0, .net remoting is the way to go in this situation.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Remoting

Winform app can expose objects via remoting. Web app can send request to these objects. request would have commands.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I searched.